# Trouble with UL size

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make a simple ul for social icons li... but the li margin is somehow not being considered into the ul width... so i get my follow txt overlapped by the overflowing li s... i think this would be solved if the width of the ul could be made to fit all the li s dimension... but i cant seem to get the ul width to be what it should... can anyone enlighten me? ive tried many many things and still cant get the damn ul width be the right size!

```css
.ps-abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.ps-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.ps-fix {
  position: fixed;
}

.ps-stk {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.flex, .flex-r, .flex-c {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-r {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-c {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-jc-c {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.flex-jc-l {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-jc-r {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-jc-sb {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-ai-c {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.flex-wp-w {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.of-hd {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vs, .vs-nn {
  visibility: visible;
}

.vs-nn {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dm-f {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dm-h-f {
  height: 100%;
}

.dm-h-hf {
  height: 50%;
}

.dm-w-f {
  width: 100%;
}

.dm-w-hf {
  width: 50%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ExoRegular;
  src: url(../assets/typography/Exo-Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ExoMedium;
  src: url(../assets/typography/Exo-Medium.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ExoSemiBold;
  src: url(../assets/typography/Exo-SemiBold.ttf);
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
      align-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: ExoRegular;
}

a, a:visited, a:hover {
  font-family: ExoRegular;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

p {
  font-family: ExoRegular;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  font-size: calc(0.5rem + 0.74vw);
  letter-spacing: calc(0.095rem + 0.15vw);
  line-height: calc(0.8rem + 0.74vw);
}

h1 {
  font-family: ExoSemiBold;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  font-size: calc(0.6rem + 0.74vw);
  letter-spacing: calc(0.095rem + 0.15vw);
  line-height: calc(0.8rem + 0.74vw);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.ps-abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.ps-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.ps-fix {
  position: fixed;
}

.ps-stk {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.flex, .flex-r, .flex-c {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-r {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-c {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-jc-c {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.flex-jc-l {
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-jc-r {
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
}

.flex-jc-sb {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-ai-c {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.flex-wp-w {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.of-hd {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.vs, .vs-nn {
  visibility: visible;
}

.vs-nn {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.dm-f {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.dm-h-f {
  height: 100%;
}

.dm-h-hf {
  height: 50%;
}

.dm-w-f {
  width: 100%;
}

.dm-w-hf {
  width: 50%;
}

/**************************
Transitions & Animations **/
.MRFadeOutRight {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
          transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.mr-div, .mr-div-c {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-div-c {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

.mr-mg-v {
  height: calc(0.2rem + 0.4vw);
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-mg-h {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(0.2rem + 0.4vw);
}

.mr-mg-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.mr-mg-ls-ovrl {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.mr-mg-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.mr-mg-rs-ovrl {
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, #080808 16.42%, #1e1e1e 42.14%, #434343 73.75%, #666666 100%);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#666666' ,GradientType=0)";
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(black), color-stop(16.42%, #080808), color-stop(42.14%, #1e1e1e), color-stop(73.75%, #434343), to(#666666));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black 0%, #080808 16.42%, #1e1e1e 42.14%, #434343 73.75%, #666666 100%);
  opacity: 0.85;
  filter: alpha(opacity=85) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=85) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000',endColorstr='#666666' , GradientType=1);
}

.mr-sec {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-header {
  height: 7.5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-header-mg-v {
  height: 31%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-header-mg-h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 2%;
}

.mr-sec-header-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-header-ls-menu, .mr-sec-header-ls ul {
  height: 38%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-header-ls-menu-item, .mr-sec-header-ls-menu li, .mr-sec-header-ls ul-item, .mr-sec-header-ls ul li {
  padding: 0.4% 0.9% 0.4% 1.2%;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.mr-sec-header-ls-menu-item:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-header-ls-menu li:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-header-ls ul-item:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-header-ls ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.mr-sec-header-ls-menu-item a, .mr-sec-header-ls-menu li a, .mr-sec-header-ls ul-item a, .mr-sec-header-ls ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: calc(0.39rem + 0.74vw);
  letter-spacing: calc(0.095rem + 0.15vw);
  line-height: calc(0.8rem + 0.74vw);
}

.mr-sec-header-ls-menu li:hover, .mr-sec-header-ls ul li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.mr-sec-header-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-hero {
  height: 27%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-mg-v {
  height: 7.5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-mg-h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 26.75%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 46.5%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-logo-img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 27,10%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: initial;
          box-sizing: initial;
}

.mr-sec-hero-logo-img img {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 27,10%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-nav {
  height: 45%;
  width: 45%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-nav-next {
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.mr-sec-hero-nav-prev {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(../img/svg/arrow.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mr-sec-hero-ovrl {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.31;
  filter: alpha(opacity=31);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
          box-shadow: 0px -5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.mr-sec-hero-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-hero-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-main {
  height: 63%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-main-mg-v {
  height: 22%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-main-mg-h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 12%;
}

.mr-sec-main-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-main-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-main-rs-ovrl {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.55;
  filter: alpha(opacity=55);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 5s;
          transition-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.mr-sec-main-rs-ctt {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.mr-sec-main-rs-ctt h1 {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding: 1.2%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.mr-sec-main-rs-ctt p {
  padding: 1.2%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.mr-sec-footer {
  height: 2.5%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mr-sec-footer-mg-v {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-footer-mg-h {
  height: 100%;
  width: 12%;
}

.mr-sec-footer-ovrl {
  background-color: rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.795);
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.mr-sec-footer-menu-sn, .mr-sec-footer ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: max-content;
}

.mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-footer-menu-sn li:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-footer ul-item:not(:last-child), .mr-sec-footer ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item:first-child, .mr-sec-footer-menu-sn li:first-child, .mr-sec-footer ul-item:first-child, .mr-sec-footer ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.mr-sec-footer-ctt {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  min-height: 2vh;
}

.mr-sec-footer-ctt p, .mr-sec-footer-ctt a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  font-size: calc(0.28rem + 0.5vw);
  letter-spacing: calc(0.095rem + 0.15vw);
  line-height: calc(0.6rem + 0.7vw);
}

.mr-sec-footer-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-footer-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-sec-ls {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.mr-sec-ls-ovrl {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.mr-sec-ls-ovrl-img {
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../img/raster/bgleft.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.34;
  filter: alpha(opacity=34) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=34);
}

.mr-sec-rs {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.mr-sec-rs-ovrl {
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, black 0%, #080808 16.42%, #1e1e1e 42.14%, #434343 73.75%, #666666 100%);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#666666' ,GradientType=0)";
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(black), color-stop(16.42%, #080808), color-stop(42.14%, #1e1e1e), color-stop(73.75%, #434343), to(#666666));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, black 0%, #080808 16.42%, #1e1e1e 42.14%, #434343 73.75%, #666666 100%);
  opacity: 0.85;
  filter: alpha(opacity=85) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=85) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000',endColorstr='#666666' , GradientType=1);
}

.mr-sec-rs-ovrl-top {
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.31;
  filter: alpha(opacity=31);
}

.mr-sec-rs-ovrl-img {
  background-position: right center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(../img/raster/bgright.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.16;
  filter: alpha(opacity=16) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=16);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>MRLayout</title>
<link href="../css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0495976534.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#a0a0a0">


<div class="mr-sec-footer-ctt flex-jc-r">
    <p>Follow: </p>
    <!-- MENU SOCIAL NETWORKS -->
    <ul class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn">
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a></li>
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-medium-m"></i></a></li>
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li class="mr-sec-footer-menu-sn-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! The margin have no sense into a flexbox element. Try without flex, or you must put the class .flex-wp-w on your .mr-sec-footer-ctt to force the second line and not overlap.

Comment: well... ty for answering! i've changed the ul to display inline-block and also the li. now the ul takes the width of the nested li... but im getting a weird result.... the icons break line after a certain width... but i want all the li on the same line!!!

Comment: the margin with % and width: max-content; doesn't work fine together, if just change the 5% to 5px everything puts in his place. That's a problem between flex and %.

Answer (score 0):

Flex-box not count % margin inside her and that's why your flex element is not growing properly.
On flex box use justify-content and margin with other unit to correct his size.

Hope this will work and find the solution.